# Why is Struts2 converting my string to a string array?

Tags: java, struts2

I have a Struts 2 (JDK 1.7, Struts 2.2.1) application that contains a list of filtering criteria, stored as strings in a map.

```
Map< String, String > m_filters = new HashMap< String, String >();

public Map< String, String > getFilters() {
    return m_filters;
}
```

I pass a URL formatted like this:

http://myserver.com/myapp/GenerateReport.action?reportID=Whatever&filters.fromDate=0&filters.toDate=2000000000&filters.FcsType=piv_cardholder_3kp&detailed=true

Even though the Map has both key & value types specified as String, attempting to get a value from this

```
    Map< String, String > filters = getFilters();
    String value = filters.get( "fromDate" );
```

causes this exception to be thrown:

`java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.String; cannot be cast to java.lang.String`

I reproduced this in a unit test, and confirmed in a debugger that Struts 2 seems to be creating a String[1] instead of a String for each of the parameters.  i.e. it is a length-1 string array with the only string being the expected value ("0" in this case).

**My question is:** Is this a bug in Struts2, or am I doing something incorrectly?

If it is a bug, is there a known workaround?

Comment: Can you try String value = (java.lang.String) filters.get( "fromDate" ); and run?

Comment: Well, the problem is the map contains String[] entries, not Strings, even though it is parameterized (sp?) with <String, String>, so an explicit cast would still cause the error.

Comment: +1 btw because this was interesting I'm not certain the struts2 behaviour in this case is the most sensible. It is true you should be following conventions but it is also true that what you are experiencing isn't intuitive.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are no issues if you follow Java bean conventions.

Here are some guidelines to resolve the issue:

- This issue does not happen if you name the private member "filter" and provide only a getter for filter.
- This issue does not happen if you provide a public setter (even if you use a different name for the private member such as m_filter) in addition to the getter
- this issue only happens if you do not provide a setter and the property does not have the same name as the getter.

Long story short follow conventions. Above behaviour tested with Struts 2.3.4

**What I'm guessing is happening**: The getter allows for setting too (If there was only a setter you could only set one item in the map, well with the current parameter interceptor this is the case). The bean is inspected for the property to see how it should do type conversion probably first it looks for a setter failing that it looks at the action for a propterty of that name to determine the type failing that it will need to use the default. The default parameter type is a mapping of String to String[] and this is what you are seeing.

Comment: Agree. @Shawn D.: Create correct getter/setters and it should work.

Comment: @ShawnD Did you try Quaternion's suggestion? Did it work for you?

Comment: This was it.  I figured I didn't need a setter for the Map because it was pre-allocated, so Struts2 wasn't going to need to create one for me.  However, without the setter, *even though it never calls the setter* it doesn't know what type to use for the Map and so passes it as a string array.  Good catch.

Comment: In my case I was missing the getter, even though my code never uses it. Struts uses the setter to add an empty Map, and then calls the getter to get the Map and add items to it.

Answer (score 4):

You're using the wrong notation. `filters.fromDate` would be the equivalent of `getFilters().setFromDate()`, which is not actually what you want. Dot notation is for JavaBeans.

Try using brackets, such as `filters['fromDate']`.

Refer to: http://struts.apache.org/2.2.1/docs/type-conversion.html#TypeConversion-RelationshiptoParameterNames.

Comment: Same result (ClassCastException) with filters['fromDate'].  I believe dot notation is valid for Maps, as it's used as the key unless it corresponds to a special value (like .size, which returns the size of the map).  I just can't seem to find that reference right now.

Comment: Not sure what to tell you. I've updated Maps before with the bracket convention without problem. :/

Comment: @StevenBenitez: Maps are accessed with both notations. E.g. see referencing `session` here http://struts.apache.org/2.x/docs/ognl.html.

Comment: If that is in fact true, then it would seem the documentation above lacks some clarity.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 Object[] obj = (Object[]) filters.get( "fromDate" );
 String value = (String)obj[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not a bug you can consider it's a feature. [Access RequestParameters](http://struts.apache.org/2.3.4/docs/how-can-we-access-request-parameters-passed-into-an-action.html)

[ParameterAware Interceptor](https://struts.apache.org/2.3.4/struts2-core/apidocs/org/apache/struts2/interceptor/ParameterAware.html)

Let us suppose /http://localhost:8080/myApp/login.action?name=struts2&name=rocks

if you try to access the name parameter string[0] = struts2, string[1](http://struts.apache.org/2.3.4/docs/how-can-we-access-request-parameters-passed-into-an-action.html)=rocks

Comment: Both your parameters have the same name.  Mine are supposed to be entries under the same map with different keys.  filters.fromDate is a unique key in the list of parameters.

Comment: As per my understanding struts2 parameterAware designed in such a way that to handle above situation.

Comment: ParameterAware looks like it is there if someone needs access to all the request parameters.  In my case, I'm trying to determine why passing a single string, even if there are no other parameters, it gets converted to a length-1 string array.

Comment: `ParameterAware` is unrelated to the problem Shawn is having.