# Struts2 String[] parameter instead of Long

Tags: java, struts2

I am developing a struts2 application (Struts 2.3.14, java 1.7, on a Tomee plus 1.5.1 server).

I have a bunch of "detail" actions, and all of them contain the following code:

```
private Long modelId;

public Long getModelId() {
    return modelId;
}

public void setModelId(Long modelId) throws Exception {
    this.modelId = modelId;
    (...some other stuff...)
}
```

In every action I also have a "persist" action that I use to save data, like this one:

```
@Action(value = "persistEntity", results = {
    @Result(name = "success",        location = "entityDetail", 
            type = "redirectAction", params   = {"modelId", "%{modelId}"})
})
public String persist() throws Exception {
    this.modelId = [save method invocation]

    return "success";
}
```

After saving I try to redirect the user back to the detail page, but I get the following error:

```
Unexpected Exception caught setting 'modelId' on 'class classpath.DetailAction': 
Error setting expression 'modelId' with value '[Ljava.lang.String;@43b5d2fe'
```

So, it seesm like Struts is handling my masterId as a String array... I had a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13612506/why-is-struts2-converting-my-string-to-a-string-array), but it was no help for me.

What is most strange to me, after I get this error I get the same error every time I try to enter an existing entity, but if I restart my application I can enter existing entities without any error.

Thank you!

Comment: Can you print `this.modelId` value before returning "success" ?

Comment: Even better, take a look at (and possibly report here) the `modelId` parameter with **Firebug's NET Module** after the *redirect*. I suspect it's "doubled", hence the array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, turns out I was misleaded by Struts2 error message... The framework was correctly trying to set the parameter in my action, but I had an exception thrown by the

```
(...some other stuff...)
```

section. I went through the whole log file, and finally found the real issue.

Thank you anyway.

Comment: Ha, ha, ha. This is really solution :D

Comment: @RomanC I once more learned the importance of logging and the many problems that (un)clear error messages can help to solve (or create). ^__^

Comment: You need to take more attention on exception handling, the framework is not since you got an exception you don't understand.